# Parse JSON, find matches of values and store in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, parsing

I have having trouble figuring out how I can limit my output.  I have to compare values of each attribute within an object, however I only want 1 output per ID.

Any thoughts?

//example JSON

```
var obj1 = {
"Summary" : 
[
    {
        "ID" : "1234", 
        "Name" : "John", 
        "Status" : "Green",
    },
    {
        "ID" : "5678", 
        "Name" : "Mike", 
        "Status" : "Green",
    },
    {
        "ID" : "9012", 
        "Name" : "Tom", 
        "Status" : "Red",
    }

]
};
```

//my code

```
var attributesvalues = ["Mike", "Green", "Red"];
var sg1 = [];
var k;
var l;


//push name of each attribute value to a new array
//one example
sg1.push(attributesvalues[0]);

 //go through each ID, if name value exist, push the #1, if not, push nothing
 for (k = 0; k < obj1.Summary.length; k++) {
 for (l in obj1.Summary[k]) {
    if (sg1[0] == obj1.Summary[k][l]){
    sg1.push("1");
    }
    else{
    sg1.push("");   
    }
 }

 }
```

output should look like this - I only want 4 values, name + a 1 or "" for each ID(3)

sg1 = ["Mike", "", "1", ""]
sg2 = ["Green", "1", "1", ""]

instead I am getting this - the name + a 1 or "" for each attribute.

sg1 = ["Mike", "", "", "", "", "1", "", "", "", ""]
sg2 = ["Green", "", "", "1", "", "", "1", "", "", ""]

Any additional pointers or tips you could provide would be much appreciated.  I am still trying to get the hang of JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't know if you have a match or not until you finish the entire `for-in` loop.

```
var found;

for (k = 0; k < obj1.Summary.length; k++) {
    found = "";
    for (l in obj1.Summary) { 
        if (obj1.Summary[i][l] == sg1[0]) {
            found = "1";
            break;
        }
    }
    sg1.push(found);
}
```

Comment: Barmar thanks for the quick answer - Unfortunately, what I left out (I will update) is that I may also need to match status or ID.  This is a simplified example of what my JSON looks like, but my "attributesvalues" array may have like 50 different values in it, which means I may have to keep going back and forth between the different attributes.

Comment: I've revised the answer.